# c# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream Authorization

Tags: c#, http-post, httpwebrequest, asp.net-authorization

I got a web Api Controller which is flagged with the Authorize tag.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

```
[Authorize()]
public class SomeController : ApiController {}
```

I'm using HttpWebRequest to do a Post-Request to that controller as follows:
(Please note, I do not provide an authorization header in order to show my issue)

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SomeUrl");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

StreamWriter streamWriter;

// 1) no error here, works without authentication
using (streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"Message\":\"Test\"," + "\"Data\":\"\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}


// 2) here I get a 401: not authorized
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

**Problem:**
I expected to get a not authorized exception, when asking for the request stream. But I can call GetRequestStream and even write to that stream, without any issue. 
Only when GetRespone is called, I get the 401 (Not Authorized) which I expected earlier.

I'm just wondering, if this is intended behaviour? And If there is any way to change that. For example, if I want to upload a huge file, all the data will be uploaded before the client is informed that it is not authorized to do so. Somehow that does not make sense to me? Or do I miss something?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. You will only get response after you actually make the request. HTTP doesn't maintain any status which means that you could not get any information ahead of time.

Comment: but when I call GetRequestStream I actually already create a connection to the server and send the request headers.
When I write to the stream I already upload data to the server (or not?). It seems confusing to do that when not authorized. 
And HttpClient does it differently. HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync for example will not upload any data and will reject the request immediately. So I think it is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, ideally, the GetRequestStream() call should have resulted in the request being sent to the server, and the server responding with a 401.

I think what might be happening is that the server is waiting for you to post the data before replying with the final status. THat is why  you get the final response when you call request.GetResponse()

In any case, you should handle exceptions and do the needful.

Comment: ok thanks, I think it is just ridiculous to send the whole message body and then get rejected.